# How can I change variable of elements in vectors inside another struct?

Tags: rust

I have a similar issue as this one [How can I change fields of elements in vectors in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550632/how-can-i-change-fields-of-elements-in-vectors-in-rust).
Where I can't just seem to get it working. I have been adding '&' and 'mut' all over the place, but I am out of a clue..

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Character{
    name: String,
}

struct Characters {
    records : Vec<Character>
}

impl Characters {
    fn set_value(self, value : String) {
        for record in self.records {
            record.name = value;
        }
    }
}

fn test() {
    let  hobbits = vec![
        Character{name:String::from("Sam")},
        Character{name:String::from("Merry")},
        Character{name:String::from("Pepper")},
    ];

    let chars = Characters {
        records : hobbits
    };

    // Set all names to "Halfling 
    chars.set_value("Halfling".to_string());
}
```

This does not compile for several reasons, but my main thing is; I want to modify a variable of a struct inside another struct vector variable impl. Trying all sorts of things but am unable to get it to work.

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea99c5f9740ed8768ddaa24ba37fa93c)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35391084/4326767

Comment: Because it took me a while to realize what the diff between @Jmb and your code is: You take ownership of `self` in your `Characters::set_value`. This destroys the `self` object after the execution of the function. Use a mutable reference instead: `fn set_value(&mut self, value: String)`

Comment: @Finomnis there's also the `&mut` in the `for` loop and the `value.clone()`. Hard to say which one is relevant since the OP said he had _"been adding '&' and 'mut' all over the place"_ but didn't show exactly what he tried.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a situation in which following the compiler suggestions can get you to [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e51412f6eda95667345d587403e356b) compiling and (probably) totally useless code…

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, since you want `set_value` to change the value of a field, it needs to take `&mut self`:

```
impl Characters {
    fn set_value(&mut self, value : String) {
        for record in self.records {
            record.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This still has several errors, the first of which is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.records` which is behind a mutable reference
   --> src/lib.rs:12:23
    |
12  |         for record in self.records {
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                       |
    |                       `self.records` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    |                       move occurs because `self.records` has type `Vec<Character>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `self.records`
help: consider iterating over a slice of the `Vec<Character>`'s content to avoid moving into the `for` loop
    |
12  |         for record in &self.records {
    |                       +
```

Following the compiler suggestion, we get:

```
impl Characters {
    fn set_value(&mut self, value : String) {
        for record in &self.records {
            record.name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

giving this error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `record.name`, which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:13:13
   |
12 |         for record in &self.records {
   |                       ------------- this iterator yields `&` references
13 |             record.name = value;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ `record` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

Here the compiler doesn't give a straight solution, but it suggests that the issue is that `record` is not mutable. Unfortunately simply using `for mut record` doesn't change anything. The solution is actually the same as the first change we made: since we want to modify `self.records`, we need to borrow it mutably: `for record in &mut self.records`.

While we're here, let's look at the second error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `value`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:27
   |
11 |     fn set_value(&mut self, value : String) {
   |                             ----- move occurs because `value` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
12 |         for record in &self.records {
13 |             record.name = value;
   |                           ^^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

This makes sense: once we've moved `value` in the first `record`, we don't have it anymore so we can't put it in the others. We can ask the compiler for more explanations on the error with [`rustc --explain E0382`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0382) and we get the solution in the third example:

> Sometimes we don't want a reference, but a duplicate. All types marked `Clone`
> can be duplicated by calling `.clone()`.

If we clone `value`, we get:

```
impl Characters {
    fn set_value(&mut self, value : String) {
        for record in &mut self.records {
            record.name = value.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

And now this function compiles. There remains only one error in another part of the code:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `chars` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:30:5
   |
25 |     let chars = Characters {
   |         ----- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut chars`
...
30 |     chars.set_value("Halfling".to_string());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Following the compiler suggestion, we write `let mut chars` and we get the working solution:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Character{
    name: String,
}

struct Characters {
    records : Vec<Character>
}

impl Characters {
    fn set_value(&mut self, value : String) {
        for record in &mut self.records {
            record.name = value.clone();
        }
    }
}

fn test() {
    let  hobbits = vec![
        Character{name:String::from("Sam")},
        Character{name:String::from("Merry")},
        Character{name:String::from("Pepper")},
    ];

    let mut chars = Characters {
        records : hobbits
    };

    // Set all names to "Halfling 
    chars.set_value("Halfling".to_string());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1676cb661c66074b90fa67bbb3ce7b9f)